# Boot menu is in loop

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I have a clean Windows 10 installed to my SSD drive on my PC. However, I **cannot** boot it from my SSD. When I turn on my PC, I come across with the boot menu screen as follows.
[Boot Menu](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wFkC8I2K23azJsM2h0WDBIbzQ/view?usp=drivesdk)

I pick the first one but it keeps asking it again.
Making some search in the internet, I figured out that I have to set *Legacy Boot* in BIOS settings to enabled. However it is grayed out.
[Legacy Boot Disabled](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wFkC8I2K23T1NRVzd3YjFJUGM/view?usp=drivesdk)

It is said somewhere in the internet that it can be managed from the *Advanced* tab. Unfortunately, I do **not** have anything related there.
[Advanced](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wFkC8I2K23ZnVvSmdyUFJUYm8/view?usp=drivesdk)

My BIOS model is *Phoenix SecureCore Tiano* with version number *71Q*.

**Question**. How can I make my pc boot Windows 10 again?

The complete story is as follows.
My friend has a MAC, and she needs to run Windows (based programs) from an external HDD. I could set it up. One day she told me that her Windows 10 entered into **Automatic Repair Mode** and stucked there.
I plugged her external HDD to my PC and booted from it. Indeed, it was stuck at there.
I searched the forums and learned that fixing it is to copy the files in *Windows\System32\Config\RegBack* into the previous folder *Config*.
So, I booted from my Windows 10, and followed the steps above.
It did work but I noticed that my Windows 10 does **not** shut down any more. It does restart but does **not** shut down. When I shut it down, I receive the *Windows is shutting down* screen, then a black screen, but the power led stays on. To see where this problem emerges, I installed a clean Windows 10 to my PC but still I could restart but **not** shut down. Then, searched the internet and someone suggested to take the BIOS battery out. I did so, but it did **not** let me boot into Windows 10 again as it stuck at *Boot Menu* in the first picture.

Comment: You do not want to use legacy boot. Wherever you got that information from is wrong. Windows 10 support (U)EFI just fine and works best with that. Legacy booting is supported but less than ideal. You would also have to reinstall Windows 10 to use it and Windows 10 has to make changes to the partition tables and mbr to use legacy boot mode.

Comment: Second, you can't move windows installations from PC to PC, and especially not MAC to PC, and it still be bootable. Really you should never install Windows to external media as there's simply no benefit and performance will be seriously degraded. If you attempt to move Windows to a different PC it will fail to boot as a result of trying to use the wrong drivers for the hardware... this will result in a boot loop.

Comment: @Cliff I never said I moved Windows. I installed it to the external drive itself by using the wim file. See the guide here. http://bleeptobleep.blogspot.com.tr/2013/02/mac-install-windows-7-or-8-on-external.html?m=1

Comment: My PC was working fine before I took the BIOS battery out for some time. So, what may be the problem then? Why it is not booting even from USB to reinstall Windows?

Comment: "One day she told me that her Windows 10 entered into Automatic Repair Mode and stucked there. I plugged her external HDD to my PC and booted from it."

Moving a hard drive with Windows on it between PCs *is* moving windows to a different PC.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong Oh, right! I was thinking you mean the other way. I got it. Thank you, I will keep that in mind next time!

Comment: When you removed the BIOS battery you caused the BIOS to revert to default settings. Apparently, these default settings do not leave your system in a bootable state. Most systems do not, by default, boot from USB. Your BIOS needs the power from that battery to hold on to it's settings.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong This is a tablet PC, it has no IDE or SATA connection, only USB and SSD. So, do you think there is nothing to do?

Comment: @CliffArmstrong By the way, before I took the battery out, I remember that I set the default BIOS settings (which did **not** solve my *shut down* problem) and got the same *Boot Menu* problem. But some how I was able to enable *Boot Legacy* and boot into Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is nothing to do with *BIOS* settings, it is mutliple entries of *Windows Boot Manager*. In the boot screen menu I had a total of 4 *Windows Boot Manager* option,
which should be single. Connecting my SSD to another PC by a **USD to Sata** adapter and recreating the partitions and installing a clean Windows fixed the problem.